# Number of real solution of exp equation

Tags: calculus

> Number of real solution of the equation $2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x} = 2^{3x^2-2x^3-1}$

Try: Let $f(x) = 2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}$ and $g(x) = 2^{3x^2-2x^3-1}$

So Here $f(x) = 2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}$ is periodic function with period $2\pi.$

and From graph $f(x)\in \bigg[2^{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\;,2^{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\bigg].$

Now $g(x) = 2^{3x^2-2x^3-1}$. Then Using Derivative test

$\displaystyle g'(x) = 2^{3x^2-2x^3-1}\cdot (6x-6x^2)\ln(2)=6x(1-x)\underbrace{g(x)\ln(2)}_{\bf{always \; +ve}}$

So $g'(x)>0$ when $0<x<1$ and $g'(x)<0$ when $x<0$ or $x>1$

and $g(x)=2^{3x^2-2x^3-1}\rightarrow +\infty$
 When $x\rightarrow -\infty$

and $g(x)=2^{3x^2-2x^3-1}\rightarrow 0$
 When $x\rightarrow +\infty$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+and+minimum+y%3D2%5E(3x%5E2-2x%5E3-1)

Could some help me how can i calculate number of real solution of $f(x)=g(x)$

Thanks

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7x6tbrdo4p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analytically solve 
$$ 2^{\sin x} + 2^{\cos x} = 2^{-2x^3 + 3x^2 - 1} $$
We need to break it into cases. Let the LHS be $f(x)$ and the RHS be $g(x)$. Differentiating the RHS gives
$$ g'(x) = -6x(x-1) \cdot \ln 2 \cdot 2^{-2x^3+3x^2-1} $$
which is always negative when $x>1$. Since $g(1)=1$ which is less than the minimum value of $f$ which is approximately $1.225$, there is no solution for all $x\geq 1$.

---

To see that the minimum value of $f$ is $1.225$, we can use AMGM:
$$ 2^{\sin x} + 2^{\cos x} \geq 2\cdot 2^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos(x-\pi/4)} \geq 2\cdot 2^{-\sqrt{2}/2} ≈ 1.22509. $$

---

Now notice that when $x=0$, $g'(x)=0$, so it is a local minimum of $g$. In fact, $0$ and $1$ are the only two turning points of $g$, and since both are less than the minimum of $f$, it is safe to say that there is no solution for all $x\geq 0$.

Then for $x<0$, $g$ is strictly decreasing. It passes through the minimum and maximum values of $f$ at around $x=-0.55$ and $x=-0.77$ (you can solve this analytically quite easily, but I just used Desmos to get an approximation). Notice that within this range, $f$ is strictly increasing (either see from the graph or differentiate and see it analytically). Thus there can only be one solution within this range. In fact, there has to be a solution, since $f$ and $g$ are bounded within the same range $(-0.77,-0.55)$. It so happens that this solution is around $x=-0.71$, and this is the unique solution.